# Why is there a question mark in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, nuances

For context, Rui is telling Nene that no one liked his play idea, and Nene responds with:

そう、なんだ……
……でも……
わたしは……類のショー、好きだよ？

Does the "?" have a special significance?

Comment: Question mark can signify not only question in grammatical sense, but also sentences with rising intonation at their end, as non-traditional usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question mark indicates the rising intonation for seeking the listener's agreement or response. In English, it's like "..., you know?", "..., didn't you know?", or "..., huh?".